# Console integration: get number of errors/warnings thrown?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, frontend

So if you open up the inspector, you get this (if you're unlucky):

[image]

I'm building a tiny JS component which displays debugging information - is there any way to read the number of encountered errors and warnings so far?

A hacky solution I could come up with involves a bit of trickery by replacing the `console.(error|log|warn)` functions with my own, but I'm yet to test if it works for all cases (e.g. outside of code I own).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need some kind of wrapper around the code to catch otherwise-uncaught exceptions or you need to tie into the console API somehow.

Comment: You can probably use [devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) using a chrome extension.

Comment: maybe you can use window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error)

Comment: I found this article that may help using window.onerror():https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-even-on-chrome-and-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242/1045650) answer, it's generally not a good idea to change the behavior of native objects/methods.  However, the following code should get you what you need in a fairly innocuous manner:

```js
// Add this IIFE to your codebase:
(() => {
 // Get all of the property names of the console:
 const methodsToTrack = Object.keys(window.console);
 // Create an object to collect total usage tallies in:
 const usageRegistry = {};
 for (let i = 0, j = methodsToTrack.length; i < j; i++) {
  let methodName = methodsToTrack[i];
  // If the property is not a method, don't touch it:
  if(typeof window.console[methodName] !== 'function') {
   continue;
  }
  // Cache the original console method here:
  let consoleMethod = window.console[methodName];
  // Overwrite console's method to increment the counter:
  window.console[methodName] = function () {
   // Defining registry properties here, so the registry only contains values for methods that were accessed:
   usageRegistry[methodName] = usageRegistry[methodName] || 0;
   // Execute the original method's behavior, capturing the returned value (if any) in a var, to return it at the end:
   const returnedValue = consoleMethod(...arguments);
   // Increment the usage registry for the executed method:
   usageRegistry[methodName]++;
   // Return the value the console's method would have returned, so the new method has the same signature as the old.
   return returnedValue;
  };

 }
 // Define a funciton to output the totals to a console log, then clean up after itself:
 window.showConsoleTallies = function () {
  window.console.log(usageRegistry);
  usageRegistry['log']--;
 }
})();

// Examples:
showConsoleTallies();
console.log('log 1');
console.error('error 1');
console.log('log 2');
console.warn('warn 1');
console.error('error 2');
console.log('log 3');
showConsoleTallies();
```

PS: That's the ECMA6 version, but feel free to [run it through Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Add%20this%20IIFE%20to%20your%20codebase%3A%0A%20%20%20%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%2F%2F%20Get%20all%20of%20the%20property%20names%20of%20the%20console%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09const%20methodsToTrack%20%3D%20Object.keys(window.console)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%2F%2F%20Create%20an%20object%20to%20collect%20total%20usage%20tallies%20in%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09const%20usageRegistry%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%2C%20j%20%3D%20methodsToTrack.length%3B%20i%20%3C%20j%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09let%20methodName%20%3D%20methodsToTrack%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%2F%2F%20If%20the%20property%20is%20not%20a%20method%2C%20don't%20touch%20it%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09if(typeof%20window.console%5BmethodName%5D%20!%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09continue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%2F%2F%20Cache%20the%20original%20console%20method%20here%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09let%20consoleMethod%20%3D%20window.console%5BmethodName%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%2F%2F%20Overwrite%20console's%20method%20to%20increment%20the%20counter%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09window.console%5BmethodName%5D%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Defining%20registry%20properties%20here%2C%20so%20the%20registry%20only%20contains%20values%20for%20methods%20that%20were%20accessed%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09usageRegistry%5BmethodName%5D%20%3D%20usageRegistry%5BmethodName%5D%20%7C%7C%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Execute%20the%20original%20method's%20behavior%2C%20capturing%20the%20returned%20value%20(if%20any)%20in%20a%20var%2C%20to%20return%20it%20at%20the%20end%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09const%20returnedValue%20%3D%20consoleMethod(...arguments)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Increment%20the%20usage%20registry%20for%20the%20executed%20method%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09usageRegistry%5BmethodName%5D%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Return%20the%20value%20the%20console's%20method%20would%20have%20returned%2C%20so%20the%20new%20method%20has%20the%20same%20signature%20as%20the%20old.%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%09return%20returnedValue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%2F%2F%20Define%20a%20funciton%20to%20output%20the%20totals%20to%20a%20console%20log%2C%20then%20clean%20up%20after%20itself%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%09window.showConsoleTallies%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09window.console.log(usageRegistry)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09usageRegistry%5B'log'%5D--%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Examples%3A%0A%20%20%20%20showConsoleTallies()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('log%201')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.error('error%201')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('log%202')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.warn('warn%201')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.error('error%202')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('log%203')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20showConsoleTallies()%3B%0A) if you'd like it to be compiled for use in older browsers.

Comment: will this count 404s and exceptions like devtool's counter?

Comment: Unfortunately, @dandavis, I think it will only work to tally the console methods the developer utilizes.  `fetch('http://invalidajaxcall.com/').catch(showConsoleTallies)` (for instance) doesn't appear to use console.error, under the hood.